# How to use ExtendedCucumber runner with Cucumber version 7 or is there an alternative to override Cucumber annotations?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

Cucumber 7.9.0 version seems to have Cucumber class as final. But in our project(using Cucumber 4.0.1) there is an ExtendedCucumber runner class overriding cucumber annotations, setting up the TestRail list of scenarios etc. Please suggest how the same can be achieved with Cucumber version 7.

Adding the Extended cucumber class which sets the list of TestRail scenarios and cucumber annotations.

```
public class ExtendedCucumber extends Cucumber {

    public ExtendedCucumber(Class clazz) throws InitializationError, NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
        super(setCucumberOptions(clazz));
    }

    private static Class setCucumberOptions(Class clazz) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
        // To set the feature file path depending upon the production or preproduction environment
        TestProperties.loadProperties();
        changeCucumberAnnotation(clazz, new String [] {TestRunUtil.getFeatureFilePath()} );
        // If a Testrail ID is specified, the names of the tests are passes as an additional cucumber option ....
      
            System.setProperty("cucumber.options", prevCucumberOptions + " " + cucumberNameOption.toString());
        }
        return clazz;
    }

    private static void changeCucumberAnnotation(Class<?> clazz, Object newValue) throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
        Annotation options = clazz.getAnnotation(CucumberOptions.class);                   //get the CucumberOptions annotation
        InvocationHandler proxyHandler = Proxy.getInvocationHandler(options);              //setup handler so we can update Annotation using
        // reflection. Basically creates a proxy for the Cucumber Options class
        Field f = proxyHandler.getClass().getDeclaredField("memberValues");
        f.setAccessible(true);                                                             //suppress any access issues when looking at f
        Map<String, Object> memberValues = (Map<String, Object>) f.get(proxyHandler);      //get the key-value map for the proxy
        memberValues.remove("features");                                              //remove the key entry...don't worry, we'll add it back
        memberValues.put("features", newValue);                                            //add the new key-value pair. The annotation is now updated.
    }
}
```

Is there a way to create a list of tests/scenarios (based on testrail run) even before feature file tags are checked in Selenium and choose the right feature file path?

For example anyone who have used https://mkolisnyk.github.io/cucumber-reports/extended-cucumber-runner, what is the latest solution for doing something similar in Cucumber 7?

Comment: Right now you are asking about an https://xyproblem.info/, what is it that you are actually trying to do?

Comment: Right, I have edited my question. Please let me know if it is phrased better?

Comment: Unfortunately not, what is it that you're trying to do with TestRail?